# Command line argument not working when passing to a function while using getopts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've been trying to get some practice in with bash shell scripting but I've been having trouble using the $1 variable to reference the first argument for my script. It's a simple script that takes a file as an argument and prints the name of the file. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function practice() {
  echo "${1}"
}

while getopts "h:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
  h) practice
     ;;
  esac
done

exit 0
```

I tried the following command:

```
./practice.sh -h somefile.txt
```

For some reason it returns an empty line. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$1` in functions refers to first positional parameter passed to that function, **not** passed to your script.

Therefore, you have to pass the arguments you want to the function again. You also tell `getopts` you want to process `-h` but then you are checking for `-a` in your `case` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

practice() {
   echo "${1}"
}

while getopts "h:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
     h) practice "${OPTARG}"
        ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what I did wrong now. Also the option being a instead of h was a mistake on my part; they were all supposed to be h.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function practice() {
    echo "${1}"
}

 while getopts "h:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
  a) practice $*
    ;;
  esac
 done

exit 0
```

pass the command line arguments to the function as above.

Comment: The correct construct is `"$@"` unless the OP specifically wants to wreck the quoting.